# Словосочетание "самое главное"

Tags: синтаксис, части-речи

Заголовок книги - **"Самое главное"**. Является ли тут слово **самое** определительным местоимением? А слово **главное** - существительным?

Comment: Если рассматривать это в качестве предложения, то это односоставное назывное, распростронённое и полное?

Answer (score 2):

Разумеется. Прилагательное перешло в разряд существительного (субстантивированное прилагательное).

Answer (score 0):

Словосочетание в значении существительного.